# How can I login to multiple docker registries at same time?

Tags: docker

I want to know if docker can login to multiple repos at time and if it can push the images to them simultaneously. For example, push multiple images to AWS and Azure registries at a same time.

Comment: The one argument to `docker login` is the registry name (which defaults to Docker Hub when missing). What errors are you seeing?

Comment: No errors, just wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can login to multiple registries at the same time, but you have to push them separately, in bash you can execute commands in parallel by adding an ampersand `&` behind your command, for example:

```
docker push [MY-IMAGE] my.private.registry &
docker push [MY-IMAGE] my.private.registry2 &
```

Comment: @sahilchauhan If this answered your question, please mark it as answered.